# Enabling or Disabling Group Policies using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, group-policy

I am trying to enable group policy settings, but not able to figure out how to do it.
tried :
1) get-command grouppolicy, but throws error.
2) not able to import GPO.

Can we do this using pure powershell script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? _"but throws error"_.. What error? Add that in full to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote..But understand that i am looking for a solution to understand how it can be done..and using the get-command grouppolicy gives an error that is : The term 'grouppolicy' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Now i know you will ask to import but when i do Find-Module grouppolicy it again gives an error :  No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'grouppolicy'. Note: I am new to powershell and using it for the first time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install RSAT (Remoter Server Administration Tools) in order to have access to the Group Policy cmdlets.

You can find more information about the cmdlets here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/?view=win10-ps

RSAT can be acquired here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520